# Display delimited txt file in cmd in column row structure

Tags: cmd, command

Does anyone know how to read a .txt file in command prompt and have it displayed in a columnized structure?

Comment: Yes I do, but unless you take the [tour] , read [ask] and show just a bit of effort in research and try coding yourself I won't tell. [SO] is neither a code writing service nor a forum.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to want to parse it using a "FOR /F" Loop.

Alternatively you can pipe it into powershell.

No matter what you do you'll have to tell the scripting language how to columnize the data to some degree, as unlike an object oriented language, CMD is literally just strings.